# Adding .png Logo to my Navigation bar with react styled components

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

hello I am trying to start a beginner react project using react and styled components. I was following a tutorial that showed me how to import some stock react logos, but I can't figure out how to do it using my own image.

```
export const NavbarContainer = styled(Container)`
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
height: 80px;

${Container}
`;

export const NavLogo = styled(Link)`
color: #fff;
justify-self: flex-start;
cursor: pointer;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 2rem;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
`

export const NavIcon = styled(Icon)`
margin-right: 0.5rem;
`
```

Below is the code for my navigation bar

```
import React from 'react';
import { Nav, NavbarContainer, NavLogo, NavIcon } from './Navbar.elements';
import { ReactComponent as Icon } from './icon.png';


const Navbar = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <Nav>
                <NavbarContainer>
                    <NavLogo to="/">
                        <NavIcon />
                        SKYPRECISION
                    </NavLogo>
                </NavbarContainer>
            </Nav>
        </>
    )
}

export default Navbar
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add an img tag like this
`<img src={src} alt="My awesome logo" />`

You can replace the `NavIcon` with that.
If you want that image to utilize **styled-components** you can do something like:

```
const MyImage = styled.img`
  your css rules here
`
```

and use it in code

```
<NavLogo to="/">
  <MyImage />
  SKYPRECISION
</NavLogo>
```